# "Create" Action for nested resource with multiple Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations, nested-resources

I have `item`s, that each have multiple (threaded) `comment`s.
The threading is done via a `parent` key, that points towards another `comment`.

I just can't get the `create` action to work properly, I got it far enough to submit into the database, but it didn't have `item_id` and `parent_id` set.

I tried `form_for [@item, @comment]` instead of `form_for :comment, url: item_comments_path( @item )` but it didn't help either.

When I look at `comment_params` in the `create` action I get this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"body"=>"examplecommentgoeshere"}, "parent_id"=>"4", "commit"=>"Create Comment", "item_id"=>"4"}
```

Can anyone help?

#### Models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images,   as: :item,
                      dependent: :destroy

  validates :title,       presence: true,
                          allow_blank: false
  validates :description, presence: true,
                          allow_blank: false
  validates :user,        presence: true,
                          allow_blank: false
  validates :layout,        presence: true
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :responses,  class_name: "Comment",
                        foreign_key: "parent_id",
                        dependent: :destroy
  has_one :image,       as: :item,
                        dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent,   class_name: "Comment"

  validates :body,      presence: true,
                        allow_blank: false,
                        length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

#### Comment Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :findParent
  before_filter :find, only: [:update, :destroy, :show]
  before_filter :is_logged_in?, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :has_permission?, only: [:update, :destroy]

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    logger.debug comment_params.inspect
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @item
    else
      logger.debug @comment.errors.inspect
      session[:errorbj] = @comment
      redirect_to @item
    end
  end
  [...]
  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :parent)
  end

  private
  def find
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def findParent
    @item = Item.find params[:item_id]
  end
```

#### Item View:

```
<p>
<h3>Add a comment:</h3>
  <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { parent: @item } %>
</p>
```

#### Partial comments/form:

```
<%= form_for :comment, url: item_comments_path( @item ) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    &lt;nope&gt;
  </p>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :parent_id, parent.id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

From another stackoverflow thread I concluded that the only way to create an object in a multi-association is to do something along the lines of this:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build( comment_params.join( { parent_id: <parent.id> } ) )
```

Other stackoverflow posts however said not to do

```
@item = Item.new( item_params.join( { user_id: current_user.id } )
```

So is there really no better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is much easier than it seemed.

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :findParent, only: [:create]
  [...]
  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.item = @item
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @item
    else
      session[:errorbj] = @comment
      redirect_to @item
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there are a lot of errors in your code. i hope that i can put that into a form that might help you figure out the fix by yourself:

- use `form_for [@item, @comment]`
- `findParent` should be `find_parent`
- `findParent` should set a `@parent`
- `findParent` should find a `Comment`
- the `new` action should initialize with a parent `@comment = Comment.new parent: @parent`
- `hidden_field_tag :parent_id, parent.id` should be `form.hidden_field :parent`
- the parent association should be set via `comment_params`
- you don't need the `Rails.logger` statement, its all in logs/development.log
- don't put objects into the session
- why is there `item` and `image`?

learn more about debugging! http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: alright, `findParent` is poorly named; it finds the `item` to each `comment` (as it is the parent in the nested resource).  
  
  
In the `new` action I do not yet have the `parent`, as that is context-sensitive, it could be another comment or an item. I tried to archieve this via  the `hidden_field_tag :parent_id`.

Items and Comments may have `image`s, but I'm not sure why I have 
`as: :item` there....

I'll need to try some more things and maybe report back here.

Comment: Looking back at this now, I realized that I `parent` actually isn't polymorphic, but `image` is. `image` has an "owner post" it refers to as `item`(thus the `as :item`). The images may not be present and are therefore irrelevant to this error, I ommited them in this early stage of form-development.

Comment: The object in the session is where I take my error messages from; there might be a better way (like storing the full messages themselves) but I made sure it was always cleared and secured in a `before` filter in `ApplicationController`.

I tried `form.hidden_field :parent`, but i cannot specify a value that way, the method can only take data out of an existing `comment` object.